# Why does my Scriptable Object lose all its data after the second assembly reload?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, garbage-collection, scriptable-object

So i'm writing spell system with using some kind of spell component system. Spells itself and spell components are Scriptable Objects. Spell to create as asset and SpellComponent because non unity objects can't be properly serialized with polymorphyc classes. So when i edit freshly created spell and enter play mode they remain as i edited them. But the problem is after second assembly reload my scriptable object loses all of it's data.

I thought that it might be garbage collected. But i used hideFlags=DontUnloadUnusedAsset and it didn't worked. Then i tried using hideFlags HideAndDontSave referring to [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/serialization-best-practices-megapost.155352/) article . It didn't work and i couldn't edit my variables. Here's some code for example.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Spell", fileName = "New Spell")]
[System.Serializable]
public class Spell : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private List<SpellComponent> m_Components;

    public virutal void OnEnable()
    {
         hideFlags = HideFlags.DontUnloadUnusedAsset;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public abstract class SpellComponent : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] int m_ExampleInt;

    public virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        hideFlags = HideFlags.DontUnloadUnusedAsset;
    }
}
```

So to recreate the problem.

1. Create instance of Spell with AssetMenu
2. Add SpellComponent to Spell
3. Edit m_ExampleInt with Inspector
4. Enter playmode (m_ExampleInt will not change)
5. Enter playmode again (m_ExampleInt will be 0)

Comment: Out of curiosity regarding the design, what are the `SpellComponents` supposed to do? So if I have a freezing spell, the spell spawns a FreezingComponent or...? I ask, because code design is critical to the workflow of any application and unfortunately, Unity isn't always keen on obeying C# rules to the letter since it's a C++ engine (constructor "usage" or rather "not-usage" in Unity objects is the best example but not the only one). What I mean is, there might be less complicated ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Also, `SpellComponent` is an `abstract` class. So it "itself" will not be serialized since it cannot be instantiated. Also note, the article is for a specific use case. There is no need to forcefully use `[Serializable]` on a SO since it is already serialized (at least from my experience, I never had to do it), neither use the `HideFlags` (or maybe, again, in rare cases). Please describe the actual workflow of how Spells are supposed to work so we can better help. (including the way you set them up in the Editor). So far, `CreateAssetMenu()` has always been enough for me.

Comment: @TheNomad
I have CustomEditor for my Spell SO it adds 2 buttons : "AddComponent, DeleteComponent". DeleteComponent deletes last object from list, AddComponent have EditorGUILayout.Popup that has names of every class that derives from SpellComponent (Types i get from System.Reflection). Then i add it to list with ScriptableObject.CreateInstance(Type type). And i think the main problem is that this instance just get Garbage collected. About SpellComponent each of them triggers some event or adds custom script to Spell game object wich gets instantiated later.

Comment: Oh and i just noticed that if you get rid of abstract in SpellComponent class after 2nd entering playmode it don't just delete data anymore it like cast my component to base class wich is SpellComponent. Example: [link](https://imgur.com/a/leJ7DGr)

Comment: Well yea, that is why I said to not make it abstract in my previous comment. Serialization works for instances. So everything works now correctly?

Comment: @TheNomad yep just added answer to my own question. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. First of all Unity supports polymorphic serialization without you needing to derive from Unity.Object. You just need to mark it as SerializedReference.

```
[SerializeReference] private List<SpellComponent> m_Components;
```

Comment: Are you sure this works in a final build? The Editor is not the same environment as a build (and I am not talking about the operating system as a difference).